# Magento 2 custom module install issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, module, extensions

I create a new custom module for Magento 2 and I can't install it through composer. This is the error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - The requested package mycustom/module could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
      Problem 2
        - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
        - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
        - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) or value of "config.platform.php" in composer.json does not satisfy that requirement.
        - Installation request for magento/framework == 101.0.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.0].

    Potential causes:
     - A typo in the package name
     - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
       see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

    Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "mycustom/module",
    "description": "New module for test",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.22|~5.5.23|~5.5.24|~5.5.25|~5.5.26|~5.5.27|~5.5.28|~5.5.29|~5.5.30|~5.5.31|~5.5.32|~5.5.33|~5.5.34|~5.5.35|~5.5.36|~5.5.37|~5.5.38|~5.6.0|~5.6.1|~5.6.2|~5.6.3|~5.6.4|~5.6.5|~7.0.2|~7.1.0|~7.1.1|~7.1.2|~7.1.3|~7.1.4|~7.1.5|~7.1.6|~7.1.7|~7.1.8",
        "mycustom/module-parent": "*"
    },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Name Lastname",
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "homepage": "http://www.example.com/",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Mycustom\\Module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

How I can solve this issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use PHP version in your composer.json file.

```
"php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0"
```

Thanks